# Can not get CSS to work but same file is working on other parts of page

Tags: html, css

I have a php/html file that I am trying to style but for some reason it is not working and I am lost because other styles on the CSS file are working fine.

Here is my header (include) file

```
    <!-- ========== VIEWPORT META ========== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- ========== META TAGS ========== -->
    <meta name="description" content="Client and payment management in one place for freelancers and creative agencies.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="client relations management, payment management, software, mobile app, saas">
    <meta name="author" content="SeaitManageit">

    <!-- ========== FAVICON & APPLE ICONS ========== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <!-- ========== MINIFIED VENDOR CSS ========== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/features.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sign-up.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nav.css">


    <!-- ========== MODERNIZR ========== -->
    <script src="scripts/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Here is the include of the php/html file

```
<?php include_once("header-file.php") ?>
```

And finally the section I am working on but won't work right

```
<!-- ========== FEATURE NAVIGATION ========== -->
    <section class="se-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="feature-nav">
                    <ul>
                      <li>Analytics</li>
                      <li>Clients</li>
                      <li>Expenses</li>
                      <li>Inbox</li>
                      <li>Invoice</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div> <!-- end feature-nav -->
                </div> <!-- end col-md-12 -->


            </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end container -->
    </section>
```

Forgot the css I am testing with

```
.feature-nav  {color: blue;}
```

Based off what I have provided can anyone find the issue? As I said the main.css file works mostly but does not work for this certain div or really any div I try and change. I have cleared my cache, used incog and used a different browser so it is not my browser in any way.

Comment: Is this live somewhere?

Comment: When you say the css works are you saying it is working on the same page as the `<div class="feature-nav">`? If so, you probably have overriding `<ul>` and `<li>` styles in that css file.

Comment: Check your file paths. What happens if you comment out "<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">"? If it was working on other divs before and now none of your changes are showing up, it sounds like the file you are changing is not the one you're loading in the browser.

Comment: No it is not live anywhere only local.

Comment: I have thought about the overriding thing and have tested other things like color, background color, list style ect and nothing works.

Comment: You can use Chrome or Chromium, press F12 and you can inspect directly, which rules apply to that element

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have provided, I would assume you have `<ul>` and `<li>` styles applied in your .css somewhere which will take precedence over any div styling.

IE:

```
.feature-nav  {color: blue;}

ul li {
  color: red;
}
```

would style your list items red, not blue. Check for global list styles or consider changing your original blue font style to something more appropriate like:

```
.feature-nav ul li {color: blue;}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arrs1bry/)